# Get value of input inside first sibling <td> from dynamically created objects

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, events

I created objects from json:

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url('dashboard/admin/getPropertyList');?>";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
if(data === false) {
  var msg = 'No result';
  $('#table-panel-body').html(msg);
}else {
    var table_body = '<table id="property-table" class="table table-hover">' +
    '<thead><tr>' +
    '<th>' + "<?php echo nbs();?>" + '</th>' +
    '<th>Model Name</th>' +
    '<th>Bed</th>' +
    '<th>Bath</th>' +
    '<th>Floor</th>' +
    '<th>Lot</th>' +
    '<th>Price</th>' +
    '<th>Type</th>' +
    '<th>Modified</th>' +
    '<th>' + "<?php echo nbs();?>" + '</th>' +
    '</tr></thead>' +
    '<tbody id="property-list"></tbody>' +
    '</table>';
  $('#table-panel-body').after(table_body);
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var checkbox = '<tr><td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="',
      td = '</td><td>',
      td_buttons = 
      '<button class="btn btn-warning edit" data-target="#edit-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="edit">' + 
      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>' + 
      '</button>' + 
      "<?php echo nbs();?>" +
      '<button class="btn btn-info" data-target="#add-slide" data-toggle="modal" data-id="slide">' + 
      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>' + 
      '</button>' + 
      "<?php echo nbs();?>" +
      '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#add-tags" data-toggle="modal" data-id="tags">' + 
      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span>' + 
      '</button>' + 
      '</td></tr>';
    $( 
      checkbox + value.p_id + '"/>' + td +
      value.model_name + td +
      value.bed + td +
      value.bath + td +
      value.floor + td +
      value.lot + td +
      value.min_price + td +
      value.property_type + td +
      value.modified + td +
      td_buttons).appendTo('#property-list');
      });
    }
}); // End list populate properties
```

Now I would like to get the value of the `input` from the first `td` when I clicked a `button` from the last `td` using the following:

```
// I wrapped the table in an id because I think it's more efficient
$('#main-panel').on('click', 'button[data-id="edit"]', function() {
var inputValue = $(this).siblings('td').find('input.checkbox').val();
console.log(inputValue);
});
```

What am I doing wrong? [Here](http://tinypic.com/r/2qsugdi/8) is how it looks like.

Comment: can you provide the rendered html?

Comment: Yes, I've added the screenshot of it were the the said button is hovered by the mouse.

Comment: @JamesL.Jucutan There is a difference between a screen shot and rendered HTML: one doesn't replace the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. First you must leave to the TD from the Input reference. Than fro mthe TD get all the TDs previous and get the last one (that would be the first of the table right-to-left) and then go inside it to find the checkbox!

```
$('#main-panel').on('click', 'button[data-id="edit"]', function() {
    var jqTDs = $(this).closest('td').prevAll('td').last().find('input:checkbox').val();
    console.log(inputValue);
});
```

Or you could go to the TR and find thru the first TD...

```
$('#main-panel').on('click', 'button[data-id="edit"]', function() {
    var jqTDs = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first input:checkbox').val();
    console.log(inputValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You should find checkbox in the first td of the parent row something like this:

> `var tr = jQuery(this).closest("tr"); 
>           var firstTd = tr.find(':first-child');
>           var inputValue = firstTd.find("input.checkbox").val();`

Comment: Now I only have to add .val(). You saved the day, thank you so much.